# Oracle sql: using bind variable for dates

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

Here is a simple working query without bind variables:

```
select * from table1 where time_stamp > sysdate - INTERVAL '1' day;
```

where `time_stamp` is of type `DATE`.

I should be able to input any number of days in the above query using bind variable.

So I tried the following and does not seem to work:

```
select * from table1 where time_stamp > sysdate - INTERVAL :days day;
```

I tried entering the numeric input both as 10 and '10',for eg. You get *ORA-00933* error on 10g.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string `INTERVAL '1' day` in your original query is an interval literal, i.e. it is evaluated by the parser to a single value.  You can't replace part of it with a bind variable.

If you instead use `NUMTODSINTERVAL( 1, 'DAY' )`, then 1 is an integer literal which you should be able to replace with a bind variable.