# Spring JdbcTemplate Update Sql Command

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I'm using Eclipse with Spring, Oracle SQL and JdbcTemplate. I'm trying to delete certain data based on how old the data are, the SQL command works in Oracle Sql Developer and does what I want.

`DELETE from TABLE where DATE_COLUMN < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY;`

However, in my `DAOImpl.java`,

```
int thirty = 30;
String sql = "DELETE from TABLE where DATE_COLUMN < SYSDATE - INTERVAL ? DAY";
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, thirty);
```

I'm getting `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` whenever I do `?` and 
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index` when I do `'?'` '.

1. I'm not sure it's `?` or `"?"`
2. How do I use jdbcTemplate.update() correctly? I've tried adding the `Integer.class` argument and `params` objects but the sql command still doesn't work.

Originally I'm just trying to pass in as an `int` then I tried passing in a String number 30 but it still doesn't work.

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm connecting to the db and everything works fine, I've tried some easier sql command like

```
String sql = "select count(*) from TABLE";
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
```

and it works and returns.

EDIT: 
I can do `'30'` in place of my `?` in my `String sql = "DELETE from TABLE where DATE_COLUMN < SYSDATE - INTERVAL ? DAY";` and it runs correctly, however I do not want to hard code it.

Comment: if you execute the statement in a tool like oracle sql developer, Does it run properly?

Comment: if you replace the ? with 30 in your jdbcTemplate does it run

Comment: the statement does run properly in my oracle sql developer.
And if I replace it with '30' then yes, it does run. However I do not want to hardcode it

Comment: Try something like, Object[] params = { thirty};        int[] types = {Types.VARCHAR}; template.update(updateSql, params, types);

Comment: I meant single quotes, not double quotes. Sorry. And @reos I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle sql: using bind variable for dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829409/oracle-sql-using-bind-variable-for-dates)

Comment: @sstan, I tried it but then my program just hangs once it gets to the sql.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think that means that you got it working, but now it's waiting on a lock to be able to delete the row.  You sure you don't have any uncommitted open sessions, like in Oracle SQL Developer that you used to test the statement manually?

Comment: I do have my Oracle SQL Developer open, I was using it to test my sql commands and I rollback each time and never committ. Is there a way to check if I have any uncommitted open sessions?

Comment: A simple way is, start a new session in Oracle SQL Developer, then try to to do `select * from TABLE for update`. If it hangs as well, then you have an uncommitted transaction somewhere that is holding locks on some rows of that table.  If in doubt, close SQL Developer entirely.

Comment: I restarted my SQL Developer and it still hangs. Not sure if that link was the solution to my problem.